# ASP.Net MVC HTTPRequestBase in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have several Models which implement an interface.
I  worked it out that I need a ModelBinder to process it in my controller class when coming from the View.

I am now wondering where I should set the values of my Model.

My BindModel method currently looks as follows

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    string type = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["ModelName"];
    if (type == null) 
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException("ModelName wasn't found");
    }
    type = type.Substring(type.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "MissingDeliveryNoteNumberModel":
            MissingDeliveryNoteNumberModel mdnnModel = new MissingDeliveryNoteNumberModel(request);
            return mdnnModel;

        case "MissingCardBoxModel":
            MissingCardBoxModel mcbModel = new MissingCardBoxModel(request);
            return mcbModel;

        case "WrongItemsReceivedModel":
            WrongItemsReceivedModel wirModel = new WrongItemsReceivedModel(request);
            return wirModel;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

and the WrongItemsReceivedModel looks like this

```
public WrongItemsReceivedModel(HttpRequestBase request) : this()
{
    if (request != null) 
    {
        ModelNumberID = request.Form["ModelNumberID"];
        OrderNumber = request.Form["OrderNumber"];
        String squant = request.Form["QuantityAndSize.Quantity"];
        String selectedItem = request.Form["QuantityAndSize.SelectedItem"];

        decimal quantity = 0;
        Decimal.TryParse(squant,out quantity);
        m_QuantityAndSize.Quantity = quantity;
        m_QuantityAndSize.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

My question is: Is it okay to place the initialization logic in the Model or should I do it in the ModelBinder I wrote ?
Both work but what would be considered best practice and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to initialize your model in Binder like in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder).

The purpose is to separate your model class from the UI-technology. [HttpRequestBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase(v=vs.110).aspx) is a dependency to  that shall be prevented in model.

For example if you want to share code between different technologies and use your models in mobile application or desktop application you will need add reference to System.Web that is inadmissible (or impossible in some platforms).

Even if you're not planned to share code you may want to use your models in different projects of your solution and each of them will must have reference to System.Web that is not good scenario too because this projects in its turn can be referenced to non-web parts of your app.

Comment: seems to be a logical answer

Comment: @Bongo it's a universal rule to create platform independent solutions, not only for asp.net mvc.